# Knowing if user updates app or if a new purchase (swift 3)

Tags: swift, swift3

Is is possible to know if the user is installing a new purchase or if they are downloading an update in Swift?

I have seen this question via Android and Obj C, but not in Swift.

I am using a SQLite database, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the application version in `UserDefaults`. I am not sure, what have you find for `Objective C`, but i am sure, it has kinda the same idea.

Lets say you keep track of the versions of your app under the key `appVersion` in `UserDefaults`. Than you just read it, compare it with your current application version, and check the comparison results.
You can do this in `AppDelegate`'s

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

so every time your app starts, the current app version will be updated in `UserDefaults`.

**Example for Swift 3**

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard    
guard let currentAppVersion = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String, let previousVersion = defaults.string(forKey: "appVersion") else {
      // Key does not exist in UserDefaults, must be a fresh install
      print("fresh install")
      //  Writing version to UserDefaults for the first time
      defaults.set(currentAppVersion, forKey: "appVersion")
      return
}

let comparisonResult = currentAppVersion.compare(previousVersion, options: .numeric, range: nil, locale: nil)
switch comparisonResult {
    case .orderedSame:
        print("same version is running like before")
    case .orderedAscending:
        print("earlier version is running like before")
    case .orderedDescending:
        print("older version is running like before")
}

// Updating new version to UserDefaults
defaults.set(currentAppVersion, forKey: "appVersion")
```

Comment: Probably dumb question, but the former UserDefaults are maintained on the device after an update?

Comment: Yes, it is maintained on the device after update. Not after deletion though, but you can not do too much against that.

Comment: hold on. Under maintained you mean the latest value is being in UserDefaults?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: you need to write that manually. i edited my code and my answer.